# Swift Flow of Control (Function Calls)

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, firebase

I am writing this code:

```
func checkUserImages() {
    if (self.imagesAdded.count == 0) {
        self.success()
    } else {
        if (self.checkNetwork() == false) {
            self.displayNoNetworkConnection()
        } else if (self.checkUser() == false) {
            print("THERE IS NO CURRENT USER")
        } else {
            self.progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            self.progressHUD.label.text = "Loading"
            if (self.imagesAdded.contains("Header")) {
                print("CALL 1")
                self.uploadImage(image: self.headerImageView.image!, imageType: "headerPicture")
            }
            if (self.imagesAdded.contains("Profile")) {
                print("CALL 2")
                self.uploadImage(image: self.profileImageView.image!, imageType: "profilePicture")
            }
            self.addImageLinksToDatabase()
        }
    }
}

func uploadImage(image: UIImage, imageType: String) {
    let imageUploadData = image.mediumQualityJPEGData
    storageReference.child("users").child("\(imageType)s").child("\(currentUser!.uid)\(imageType)").putData(imageUploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true)
            self.displayError(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.imageData[imageType] = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
        }
    }
}

func addImageLinksToDatabase() {
    databaseReference.child("users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("userDetails").updateChildValues(self.imageData, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
        if let error = error { // Checks for an error
            self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true)
            self.displayError(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.success()
        }
    })
}

func success() {
    self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successfulAddPhotosSegue", sender: self)
}
```

It appears that the last line of code in the `checkUserImages()` function gets called before the the images finish uploading in the `uploadImage()` function. Because of this, there is no data ready for the `addImageLinksToDatabase()` function yet. Is this a multi-threading error and how do I go about fixing the flow so that the images upload before `addImageLinksToDatabase()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to multi-threading. The solution is simple. Just move the last line of code from checkUserImages() to the end of uploadImage().

Eg.

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage, imageType: String) {
    let imageUploadData = image.mediumQualityJPEGData
    storageReference.child("users").child("\(imageType)s").child("\(currentUser!.uid)\(imageType)").putData(imageUploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true)
            self.displayError(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.imageData[imageType] = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
        }
    }
    self.addImageLinksToDatabase()
}
```

That should work perfectly.